# Do Indians need a transit visa for a 12 hour 15 minute stopover in Saudi Arabia?

Tags: transit, indian-citizens, transit-visas, saudi-arabia

I am an Indian citizen and I will fly to Italy via Saudi Arabia. I have connecting flights in Saudi Arabia of two different airlines. I will carry only hand bag, no check-in bag.

[From this website](https://www.my.gov.sa/wps/portal/snp/servicesDirectory/servicedetails/8474/!ut/p/z0/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfIjo8zivQIsTAwdDQz9LQwNzQwCnS0tXPwMvYwN3A30g1Pz9L30o_ArAppiVOTr7JuuH1WQWJKhm5mXlq8fYWFibqJfkO0eDgDtRK6y/), I came to know that transit visa is required for more than 12 hours layover.

Now I have 5 hours layover during outbound journey.

But during the return journey, the flight from Italy is supposed to arrive in Saudi arabia at 6:30 pm and my next flight for India is on next day at 6:45 am. So I have to wait 12 hours and additional 15 minutes.

> Does additional 15 minutes matters here in this case ?

Though I will board in the flight 30 minutes before 6:45 am. So I think I am not violating the guidelines of 12 hours because I will have to wait less than 12 hours.

Any comments are welcomed.

Comment: Can you share your experience for both times, I'm in a similar situation.

Comment: Unfortunately I had to cancel my Europe trip which was for education purpose. I will never choose Saudi as transit. Very bad officers

Comment: It was very bad experience. During my 1st round trip I had just 5 hours layover and according to the rules mentioned in their site, one doesn't need transit visa. But stil they detained me in a room, ofcourse, other passengers with Wizz airline also suffered same situation. Riyadh airport authories are most unprofessional and rude, they don't speak english, even I suspect they don't understand english much. I was trying to explain their rules mentioned in their website that 5 hours layover doesn't need transit visa. It was communication problem from their side. After 6 hours, they deported me.

Comment: @MAS The rules are for single tickets... **NOT** dual ticket like a Wizz Air ticket is... You were refused entry accordingly

Comment: @NicolasFormichella, no, it is not mentioned in their website i have checked ed. Nothing mentioned about single or dual ticket. It just says "waiting time and transit rules"

Answer (score 4):

> Does 10 minutes matters here in this case ?

Absolutely, 12h is 12h, one minute overstay is one minute overstay

> Though I will board in the flight 30 minutes before 6:45 am. So I think I am not violating the guidelines of 12 hours because I will have to wait less than 12 hours.

They will take into account the flight departure time, not the boarding time

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I should apply for transit visa